# Issue of WCF: is it my own mistake?

Tags: wcf, dictionary

I defined the method below:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(UserFriendlyError))]
    bool MakeOutInvoice(Dictionary<string, string> pk, string usergid);
```

In my website, I added the service reference, the vs 2010 generated these code below:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]
public partial class ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string keyField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=0)]
    public string Key {
        get {
            return this.keyField;
        }
        set {
            this.keyField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Key");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=1)]
    public string Value {
        get {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set {
            this.valueField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

   public bool MakeOutInvoice(ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring[] pk, string usergid) {
        LPM.Web.LPTMSFinancialServiceRef.MakeOutInvoiceRequest inValue = new LPM.Web.LPTMSFinancialServiceRef.MakeOutInvoiceRequest();
        inValue.pk = pk;
        inValue.usergid = usergid;
        LPM.Web.LPTMSFinancialServiceRef.MakeOutInvoiceResponse retVal = ((LPM.Web.LPTMSFinancialServiceRef.ILPTMSFinancialService)(this)).MakeOutInvoice(inValue);
        return retVal.MakeOutInvoiceResult;
    }
```

In my opinion, it should generate the same parameter as the WCF.
 Why does it replace generating the new type parameter with the Dictionary?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: is your MakeOutInvoice method part of the wcf contract?

Comment: yes, it's a method that called for the client.

Comment: WCF is intended to be SOA.  `Dictionary` is a .NET object (yes, I know other languages have dictionary objects as well), therefore to maximize interoperability it turns the Dictionary into the definition you see in the auto-generated proxy.

Comment: Another option you can try is when you add the service, click the "Advanced" button and then under Data Type, you can tell it how to treat the Dictionary collection type.  I don't use service reference to access WCF services, so this one is just a slightly-educated guess.

Comment: Thanks Tim! I had added service reference with the option "Advanced" and nothing has changed. In order to resolve this issue, I have to serialize the Dictionary to Json string as parameter and deserialize it to Dictionary between client and server.Thanks for help again.